# call the input element through the value instead of id or name of the element in javascript method

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to disable the textarea onclick of value=1 and enable it back by clicking of radio button value=0. however  i have a condition that i have to use the same name and id for both the radio buttons.i have the existing code something  like this ..is there is any possibilty that i can call the radio button through their values in js method.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="disabilityflag" id="disabilityflag" value="0"/>    
<span>Yes</span>            

<input type="radio" name="disabilityflag" id="disabilityflag"  value="1"/>
<span>No</span>

<textarea type="text" name="disabilityspecification" id="disabilityspecification">     
</textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#disabilityflag').click(function(){
    checkeddisabilityclick();
});

function checkeddisabilityclick(){
    $('#disabilityspecification').attr("disabled",true);
    $('#disabilityspecification').addClass('disabled');
}

$('#disabilityflag').click(function(){
    $('#disabilityspecification').removeAttr("disabled"); 
    $('#disabilityspecification').removeClass('disabled');
});

if($('#disabilityflag').attr('checked')) {
    checkeddisabilityclick();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.value property inside the event handler function.

```
$('#disabilityflag').click(function(){
alert( this.value) // will correspond to the value of the element that triggered the event.
checkeddisabilityclick();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery, you can just do:

```
$('#disabilityflag[value="0"]').click(function () {
    // Yes was clicked
});

$('#disabilityflag[value="1"]').click(function () {
     // No was clicked
});
```

There's a running example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YVLr5/2/)

Update:

I like Gunner's solution better because it only places one event handler but this would be how to do it if you only wanted an event handler on one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The ID tag is supposed to be unique. Simply rename the IDs to disabilityflag_no and disabilityflag_yes and add two click events to them.

On the other hand you could do (replaced id with the name value)

```
$('[name="disabilityflag"]').click(function(){
    alert( this.value) // will correspond to the value of the element that triggered the event.
    checkeddisabilityclick();
});
```